# exchange 2010 run custom script when email arrives

Tags: email, powershell, exchangewebservices

I need to process every incoming mails of a specific mailbox and insert in an external database: sender, receivers, subject and mail content.
Emails must be processed immediately.
Mailbox is on an exchange 2010 server.
I've read about powershell scripts but i cannot find and example script that can help me.

Comment: That's too bad. Good luck with your search? Did you have a programming question? This site is for qusetions, not a place to dump your to-do list and veiled "google this for me" hints.

Answer (score 2):

There is more then enough documentation online that explains how to achieve this. If you search for Powershell EWS you should be able to find everything that you need.
Just for your information : you need to have a decent level of knowledge about Powershell and Exchange to get it to work.